# Is Past Perfect correct tense in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I have to send my opinion to my english teacher and I'm not sure if this past perfect tense is correct in this context. Firstly I used Past simple "**the things we learned about**", which also seems to me correct, but maybe past Perfect is better to emphasize that: firstly the teacher explained a topic of a lesson, learned us (so it was first action that's why past perfect), and later, during the rest of the lesson we were talking and practicing vocabulary or grammar.

I think the most important thing in this course was talking to each other, which helped to practice and to remember **the things we had learned about.**

Comment: If this is a very recent course that has just finished you should stick to the present perfect and continuous................. I think the most important thing in this course has been talking to each other, which has helped us practice and remember the things we have learned about.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose to use past perfect, you are setting the temporal focus to a time after you learnt the things - here, the time when you were talking and practising.

If you use the simple past, you are not setting a temporal focus.

Both are grammatical, both are idiomatic, and both refer to exactly the same events.

[By the way, the teacher **taught** you, they didn't **learn** you. You may also notice that I prefer the past/pp *learnt* to *learned*. Both are used in British English, but I think *learnt* is rare in American English.]